# Delay image loading with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, load

i currently need to load 123,543 images from my server but every image must go through a PHP script to generate it, the problem is that my server is very weak and it crashes after loading about 600 images, so i'm asking for a Javascript that will load 2 images / second, if possible.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered lazy loading images?

Comment: If you're willing to use jQuery, you can use the [Lazy Load Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Comment: @Barmar No, lazy only loads images at the level of the user, i need it to load ALL images, just with a slight delay

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

```
$(function() {          
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
        event : "sporty"
    });
});

$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() { $("img.lazy").trigger("sporty") }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: forgot to close </script> and the image class need the src also http://pastebin.com/3GdjueiN

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to place all the images in a container with id 'container', this code does the trick:

```
var images = [
    'image1.jpg',
    'image2.jpg'
],
container = document.getElementById('container');

function loadNextImage(index) {
    var index = index || 0,
        imageUrl = images[index],
        image = document.createElement('img');

    image.src = imageUrl;
    container.appendChild(image);

    if (index + 1  < images.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){loadNextImage(index + 1)}, 500);
    }
}
loadNextImage();
```